# No candidate version found for clang-3.2. Unable to apply some actions, aborting

Tags: apt, 18.04, software-installation, clang

Hello, all I am trying to install clang version 3.2. I want this version because I want some external options that don't exist in newer versions(dumping-objects-memory-layout).

My problem is that i can not install older version.For example when i try install

```
sudo apt-get install clang-3.2
```

i got this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package clang-3.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  clang clang-3.9
```

In addition i tried with this way

```
 sudo aptitude install clang-3.2
```

but aldo i got this message:

No candidate version found for clang-3.2
Unable to apply some actions, aborting

Furthermore I've tried to run but with no success

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

i'am running out of any other ideas.Could you please help to figure out what's happening

Comment: Not available (3.3 is in Ubuntu 14.04, but it reaches EOL in April). You'd have to build it from source.

Comment: @ fkraiem My ubuntu version is 18.04

Comment: 3.2 is not available as an official package for any version of Ubuntu. As I said, you can still install 3.3 in Ubuntu 14.04. Otherwise, build from source.

Comment: @ fkraiem thnx!